# Could not get JDBC connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am making a simple test file of employee in eclipse. But it shows an error of Could not get JDBC Connection. Please help me.

Error is

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

XMLfile is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    name="dataSource" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb" p:username="root"
    p:password="banjit" />
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    name="jdbcTemplate" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

Java code is

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/banjit/spring/springjdbc/refconfig.xml");
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) context.getBean("jdbcTemplate");
        String sql = "insert into employee values (?,?,?)";
        int result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Integer(1), "Banjit","Das");
        System.out.println("Numbers of records inserted  "+result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your database host allow jdbc?

Comment: Have you `consider[ed] upgrading MySQL client`?

Comment: yes @MWB it allows

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using and which version of MySQL Connector/J? And please post the full exception stacktrace, not just the message.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this problem, the preferred solution is to upgrade all client programs to use a 4.1.1 or higher client library. If that is not possible, use one of the following approaches:

1) To connect to the server with a pre-4.1 client program, use an account that still has a pre-4.1-style password.

2) Reset the password to pre-4.1 style for each user that needs to use a pre-4.1 client program. This can be done using the SET PASSWORD statement and the OLD_PASSWORD() function:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR
    -> 'user'@'host' = OLD_PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Comment: Suggesting to use a version 4.1.1 or higher client library is most likely wrong (those versions are ancient). The problem here is likely the OP using MySQL 8.0 with MySQL Connector/J 5.1.45 or lower). The solution would then be to upgrade to 5.1.46 or higher, or better to 8.0.13 or higher.